# RoR on OS10.11.2: kernel_require.b54:in : cannot load such file when trying to generate controller welcome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just started learning Ruby on Rails from Hartl's "Ruby on rails 3: Learn Rails by example" (but I do have rails 4.2.5). Everything worked great until I tried to deploy to Heroku - couldn't get pass the `$ git push heroku master`, so I found this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#local-workstation-setup and started over according to these instructions. Everything works perfecto, apart from `

```
$ rails generate controller welcome`

`/Users/liisvaljaots/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file --
 bundler/setup (LoadError)
        from /Users/liisvaljaots/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Users/liisvaljaots/myapp/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.1/lib/spring/commands.rb:33:in `<module:Spring>'
        from /Users/liisvaljaots/myapp/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.1/lib/spring/commands.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/liisvaljaots/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Users/liisvaljaots/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Users/liisvaljaots/myapp/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.1/lib/spring/application.rb:77:in `preload'
        from /Users/liisvaljaots/myapp/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.1/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
        from /Users/liisvaljaots/myapp/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.1/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
        from /Users/liisvaljaots/myapp/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
        from /Users/liisvaljaots/myapp/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
        from /Users/liisvaljaots/myapp/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-1.6.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/liisvaljaots/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Users/liisvaljaots/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'`
```

I'm all Googled out on this issue, maybe someone here can help.

Also, another possibly related issue is this line in my Terminal when I open it `bash: eval: line 21: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Thank you!

Comment: `gem install bundler` did ??

Comment: yes, I did install bundler

Comment: do `bundle exec rails g controller welcome`

Comment: that gives me the exact same response...